How to disable sudo permission to save Next project
I created a Next.js project with npx create-next-app, and opened the project in VSCode, when I try to save the files in the project, this error message appears.
I can save the file with Retry as Sudo, but I don't want to do it every time I save a file.
The same problem happened when I try to save it on MacOS and Kali Linux.
I tried using sudo chmod 775 contactsData.js, but it only applies to the file, not the whole project directory.
How can I save all the files in the project directory without the need to type my password every single some?
Thank you.

Post error messages here as text, not links to images.

Change Ownership of the Project Directory
You can change the ownership of the entire project directory to your user account. This will allow you to save files without needing to use sudo. Try running the following command in your terminal to change the owner of the project directory to you:
sudo chown -R username project-directory


The issue you're experiencing seems to be related to file permission settings in the project directory. You likely don't have the appropriate write permissions for the project folder or files, which is why VSCode asks you to save as sudo each time.
Here’s how you can fix this:

Change Ownership of the Entire Project Directory
Since you are the user who should be editing these files, you can change the ownership of the entire project directory to your user account. This will prevent the need to use sudo every time.

Steps:
Open your terminal.
Navigate to the parent directory of your project.
cd /path/to/your/project
Run the following command to change ownership of all files and subdirectories within the project to your user (replace  with your actual username):
sudo chown -R : .
Example:
sudo chown -R john:john .
This command recursively changes the owner of all files and directories to your user, ensuring you have permission to write to all files without sudo.

What chatbot did you use to answer my question?   Evidences: The issue you're experiencing seems to be related to..., - cd /path/to/your/project, (replace with your actual username)
